# Query was performed while backing up, but no results were obtained for more than ten minutes

Tags: database-backups, cnosdb

The problem I encountered is as described in the title. I don't know if there is any problem with my operation.

### 0. Env

```
mode: single, 
version: cnosdb 2.3.3, 
revision: 54c8f4054b664ceb23bbb8609d495584f08ca488, 
cpu: 4, 
mem: 16g
```

### 1. Reproduce step

#### 1.1 Backup

```
cnosdb-imexport export -s root:@127.0.0.1:8902 -p 'file:///etc/cnosdb/data'
```

#### 1.2 Query

```
public ❯ \c prometheus
prometheus ❯ select * from node_cpu_seconds_total order by time desc limit 1;
```

#### 1.3 Check resource

```
top - 17:09:13 up 40 days, 57 min,  4 users,  load average: 10.19, 12.05, 12.08
Tasks: 221 total,   1 running, 220 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.3 us, 16.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  4.1 id, 75.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16266304 total,   387864 free, 13787820 used,  2090620 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  2310328 free,  5947204 used.  2138268 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                    
11324 root      20   0   95.8g  12.6g   5124 S  76.0 81.0  16405:44 cnosdb
```